# I want to change the domain in th below code in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 40},
width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
padding = 0.3;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], padding);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
     .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
       .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
         .orient("left")
        .tickFormat(function(d) { return percentage(d); })

var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")   
.attr("class", "tooltip")               
.style("opacity", 0)
 .attr("align","middle");

var chart = d3.select(".chart")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

data = [
 {"name":"Product Revenue","value":420000},
 {"name":"Services Revenue","value":210000},
 {"name":"Employee Revenue","value":190000}, 
 {"name":"Fixed Costs","value":-170000},
 {"name":"Variable Costs","value":-140000}

  ];


//function to find all the positive values
var positive_val = data.filter(function(d) { return d.value > 0; });
console.log(JSON.stringify(positive_val));

//function to calculate the sum of all the positive values
var maxSum = positive_val.reduce(function(sum, d) {
return sum + d.value;
}, 0);
console.log("The maximum sum is "+maxSum);

//to calculate the new Domain by adding 120 
var yaxisRange=maxSum+120;
console.log("The y axis sum is "+yaxisRange);
var newDomain=percentage(yaxisRange);
console.log(newDomain);
var newDomain = newDomain.replace(/[!@#$%^&*]/g, "");
console.log(newDomain);

// Transform data (i.e., finding cumulative values and total)   
var cumulative = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
data[i].start = cumulative;
cumulative += data[i].value;
data[i].end = cumulative;

data[i].class = ( data[i].value >= 0 ) ? 'positive' : 'negative'
}
data.push({
name: 'Total',
end: cumulative,
start: 0,
class: 'total',
value: cumulative
 });

 x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.name; }));
 y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.end; })]);
//WHen i try to use this as my new domain,the bar increase the height 
//y.domain([0,newDomain]);


debugger;

 chart.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

 chart.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

  var bar = chart.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
   .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", function(d) { return "bar " + d.class })
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.name) +    ",0)"; });

  bar.append("rect")
   //.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y( Math.max(d.start, d.end) ); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return Math.abs( y(d.start) - y(d.end) );  })
  //function to draw the tooltip
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand()).on("mouseover", function(d) {
 // to find the parent node,to calculate the x position
 var parentG = d3.select(this.parentNode);
 var barPos = parseFloat(parentG.attr('transform').split("(")[1]);
 var xPosition = barPos+x.rangeBand()/2;
  //to find the y position
 var yPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("y"))+ Math.abs( y(d.start) - y(d.end))/2;
       tooltip.transition()     
            .duration(200)      
            .style("opacity", .9);  
      tooltip.html(d.name + "<br/>"  + percentage(d.value)) 
            .style("left", xPosition + "px")        
            .style("top",  yPosition + "px");   
        }).on("mouseout", function(d) {     
        tooltip.transition()        
            .duration(500)      
            .style("opacity", 0);   
    });

    bar.append("text")
  .attr("x", x.rangeBand() / 2)
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.end) + 5; })
  .attr("dy", function(d) { return ((d.class=='negative') ? '-' : '') + ".75em" })
  .text(function(d) { return percentage(d.end - d.start);});


   bar.filter(function(d) { return d.class != "total" }).append("line")
  .attr("class", "connector")
  .attr("x1", x.rangeBand() + 5 )
  .attr("y1", function(d) { return y(d.end) } )
  .attr("x2", x.rangeBand() / ( 1 - padding) - 5 )
  .attr("y2", function(d) { return y(d.end) } )


  function type(d) {
  d.value = +d.value;
   return d;
   }

 function percentage(n) {
  n = Math.round(n);
  var result = n;
  if (Math.abs(n) > 100) {
  result = Math.round(n/100) + '%';
  }
   return  result;
   }
```

-Here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7mkq4k8k/21/
-I want to make the yaxis label increase .for eg 9000,9500.I have calculated the newDomian.
-If i try to add this domain,my chart doesnt get drawn  properly.The height of the bars increase ,and the due to this the rest of the bars are not drawn.Please help me in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

So the chart you initially draw is based on this domain :

```
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
        return d.end;
    })]);
```

Try to `console.log(d3.max(data, function (d) {return d.end;}))` and you will find it returns 820000, which is the maximum of your cumulative calculation. That means your chart is drawn with a domain from 0 to 820000.

Now let's talk about your newDomain. You're taking **the percentage of your maxSum**, which means your newDomain is equal to 8201. So now you're trying to draw your chart from 0 to 8201.
But your bars height is calculated like this :
`Math.abs(y(d.start) - y(d.end))`, which means you are calculating ranges from y(0) to y(820000) (d.end is max equal to 820000).

y(820000) doesn't fit, as you specified with your domain that it could max go to y(8201). That's why your bars are reaching over the very top of your chart, because the domain you're giving doesn't correspond the numbers inside :
y(this number is too big and doesn't fit because it is not between 0 and newDomain).

How to solve this ?
You define your domain correctly, removing the percentage line

```
//function to calculate the sum of all the positive values
var maxSum = positive_val.reduce(function (sum, d) {
    return sum + d.value;
}, 0);
console.log("The maximum sum is " + maxSum);

//to calculate the new Domain by adding 520000 (big number to show you it works) 
var newDomain = maxSum + 520000;
console.log(newDomain); //1340000

y.domain([0,newDomain]);
```

Working snippet below :

```js
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
},
width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    padding = 0.3;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], padding);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(function (d) {
    return percentage(d);
})

var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .attr("align", "middle");

var chart = d3.select(".chart")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

data = [{
    "name": "Product Revenue",
    "value": 420000
}, {
    "name": "Services Revenue",
    "value": 210000
}, {
    "name": "Employee Revenue",
    "value": 190000
}, {
    "name": "Fixed Costs",
    "value": -170000
}, {
    "name": "Variable Costs",
    "value": -140000
}

];


//function to find all the positive values
var positive_val = data.filter(function (d) {
    return d.value > 0;
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(positive_val));

//function to calculate the sum of all the positive values
var maxSum = positive_val.reduce(function (sum, d) {
    return sum + d.value;
}, 0);
console.log("The maximum sum is " + maxSum);

//to calculate the new Domain by adding 120 
var newDomain = maxSum + 520000;
console.log(newDomain);

// Transform data (i.e., finding cumulative values and total)   
var cumulative = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    data[i].start = cumulative;
    cumulative += data[i].value;
    data[i].end = cumulative;

    data[i].class = (data[i].value >= 0) ? 'positive' : 'negative'
}
data.push({
    name: 'Total',
    end: cumulative,
    start: 0,
    class: 'total',
    value: cumulative
});

x.domain(data.map(function (d) {
    return d.name;
}));
console.log(d3.max(data, function (d) {
    return d.end;
}));
            
/*y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
    return d.end;
})]);*/
//WHen i try to use this as my new domain,the bar increase the height 
y.domain([0,newDomain]);


debugger;

chart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

chart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

var bar = chart.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", function (d) {
    return "bar " + d.class
})
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
    return "translate(" + x(d.name) + ",0)";
});

bar.append("rect")
//.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
.attr("y", function (d) {
    return y(Math.max(d.start, d.end));
})
    .attr("height", function (d) {
    return Math.abs(y(d.start) - y(d.end));
})
//function to draw the tooltip
.attr("width", x.rangeBand()).on("mouseover", function (d) {
    // to find the parent node,to calculate the x position
    var parentG = d3.select(this.parentNode);
    var barPos = parseFloat(parentG.attr('transform').split("(")[1]);
    var xPosition = barPos + x.rangeBand() / 2;
    //to find the y position
    var yPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("y")) + Math.abs(y(d.start) - y(d.end)) / 2;
    tooltip.transition()
        .duration(200)
        .style("opacity", .9);
    tooltip.html(d.name + "<br/>" + percentage(d.value))
        .style("left", xPosition + "px")
        .style("top", yPosition + "px");
}).on("mouseout", function (d) {
    tooltip.transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style("opacity", 0);
});

bar.append("text")
    .attr("x", x.rangeBand() / 2)
    .attr("y", function (d) {
    return y(d.end) + 5;
})
    .attr("dy", function (d) {
    return ((d.class == 'negative') ? '-' : '') + ".75em"
})
    .text(function (d) {
    return percentage(d.end - d.start);
});


bar.filter(function (d) {
    return d.class != "total"
}).append("line")
    .attr("class", "connector")
    .attr("x1", x.rangeBand() + 5)
    .attr("y1", function (d) {
    return y(d.end)
})
    .attr("x2", x.rangeBand() / (1 - padding) - 5)
    .attr("y2", function (d) {
    return y(d.end)
})


function type(d) {
    d.value = +d.value;
    return d;
}

function percentage(n) {
    n = Math.round(n);
    var result = n;
    if (Math.abs(n) > 100) {
        result = Math.round(n / 100) + '%';
    }
    return result;
}
```

```css
.bar.total rect {
    fill: steelblue;
}
.bar:hover rect {
    fill:orange;
}
.bar.positive rect {
    fill: darkolivegreen;
}
.bar:hover rect {
    fill:orange;
}
.bar.negative rect {
    fill: crimson;
}
.bar:hover rect {
    fill:orange;
}
.bar line.connector {
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-dasharray: 3;
}
.bar text {
    fill: white;
    font: 12px sans-serif;
    text-anchor: middle;
}
.axis text {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.axis path, .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
div.tooltip {
    position:absolute;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2px;
    font: 12px sans-serif;
    background: #33CC00;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    pointer-events: none;
    width: 90px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg class="chart"></svg>
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: thankyoy thankyou thankyou ...this really helped me !!